# What Tag Term Should We Use For Questions in Regards to Fixing Mistakes?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I've come across several questions about fixing a mistake in a recipe the OP is working on. I was trying to come up with a new tag to incorporate such a genre of questions but came up short. "Fix" seems somehow inadequate.

Take this for example: [How Do I Fix Curdled Mascarpone Cheese?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20399/8305)

Can anyone else think of a better term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please review our existing [tagging guidelines](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/what-is-the-purpose-of-tags-how-do-i-use-them-appropriately).

[fix](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fix), [salvage](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salvage), [mistake](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mistake) and the similar tags that were discussed on chat today are not appropriate uses of tags. These are basically no different than a [help](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help) tag. These are all meta-tags that are entirely too broad and the benefit they seem to provide is illusory.

There will not exist a subject-matter expert on "fix". However there do exist SME's on [sauce](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sauce), [bbq](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bbq), or [baking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baking). If I have a problem with a problem with a messed up hollandaise I'm going to search for "hollandaise" which will provide relevant results. Searching for "fix" would provide broad useless results.

For additional historical reference please also refer to "[Tags that might be meta ...](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/472/60)

Comment: See also a list of similar [tags that were deleted](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/467/60)

Comment: I'm not sure—covering up mistakes is a skill itself, and I could see someone being an expert on it. Not sure what word to use to describe it (unless we made our own up).

Comment: @derobert, no it's not. It might be a *specialization* of a skill, but if you've never made Hollandaise then you're not going to be able to give good advice on how to fix it/cover it up based on experience with a few failed/failing cakes. The only people who might be experts in fixing *any* or even *many* kinds of recipes would also be experts in all of the applicable cuisines and techniques, bringing us back to hobodave's original point. This is programmer imperialism at work, thinking that anything you *can* find in common actually *matters* and must be moved to a subroutine somewhere.

Comment: @Aaronut: I'm convinced, then, it's a specialization, thus we shouldn't have a general tag for it. And at our size, it'd be silly to have a tag for each of those different skills' specializations. (As for that programmer imperialism, I'm going to have to work on that—on some of my fellow programmers. You mean you're not supposed to copy & paste it? *grumble*)

Comment: @Aaronut I like that. "programmer imperialism". :)